# different threshold value of 2 inverters

Tags: digital-logic, oscillator, inverter

[image]What is the meaning of having 2 series inverters, one with the switching threshold at 1.025 V and the other with the threshold at 0.3V?

What does this difference between the switching levels mean?

The circuit has a sine wave at the input of the inverters and it makes a clock signal from 1.8V to 0V.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching threshold means inverter is working when the input more than threshold (kind a comparator) . So In your circuit 1.035v inverter's duty cycle is %43.5 other's duty cycle is %83.If you want %50 duty cycle you should chose a inverter with 0.9V switching threshold.Also if you connect these inverters parallel they short circuit each other because of phase difference (one is positive when the other negative (or ground))

Comment: they are in a series connection

Comment: Can you add circuit's schematic ? Is it like this : Input>1.035v inverter>0.3V inverter>output

Comment: picture added. Q1 is the signal coming from an quartz

Comment: I don't want to lose my time for circuit analysis so which ones inverter (1.035v ) and inverter (0.3v) ?

Comment: the first is 1.035v and the second is 0.3V

Comment: M16&M11 first and M17&M12 second ?

Comment: yes. with a sine wave from Q1

Comment: Input sinus voltage values ? -1.8 to 1.8 or 0v to 1.8v

Comment: 0.4 to 1 V only.

Comment: I was going to write a answer but I found this link : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/81419/what-is-switching-threshold Answer is consuming too much time .